# Can't import from python module md5hash

Tags: python, module, init

I'm getting an error that python "cannot import name 'scan' from 'md5hash' and then references the path (C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\md5hash__init__.py)

This seems to happen for all modules, not just md5hash.  Originally I had read that this was a bug with PyCharm IDE, so I ditched that, but I'm seeing the same problem in IDLE.  I have tried reinstalling the module and checking to see if something is inside **init**.py, but it is a blank file, as expected.  Still not sure what's going on here.

```
from md5hash import scan
path = input("Enter the absolute path to your files: ")
print(scan(path))
```

**EDIT:**  Think I may have discovered the source of the problem: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-init-py-trap... Will report back if / when I've fixed it.

**EDIT2:** Well I reinstalled pycharm, python, and pip.  I read that reinstalling the md5hash module directly from within PyCharm will help, but I'm still getting a similar error and my code will not run:  "Cannot find reference 'scan' in '**init**.py'."  I read that simply disabling the IDE warning for uncaught references will resolve this, but so far no luck.

**EDIT3:** added an **all** statement to the beginning of the init file and restarted pycharm.

```
__all__ = ['size', 'calculate', 'scan', 'md5', 'Profiler']
```

Still not working.  And the problem appears to be with all modules.  It's doing it with numpy, as well.